# Wpf Converter - Dependency Injection in Xaml

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, prism, converters

I am trying to use dependency injection for my converter in the Xaml code as described at:
[https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/releases/tag/7.1.0-pre1][1]

This requires the use of Prism.Forms

```
xmlns:ioc="clr-namespace:Prism.Ioc;assembly=Prism.Forms"
```

this though causes a conflict

```
Error   CS0433  The type 'IDialogService' exists in both 
'Prism.Forms, Version=7.2.0.1422, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 
'Prism.Wpf, Version=7.2.0.1422, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40ee6c3a2184dc59'
```

- Isn't Prism.Forms for Xamarin forms app only?
- Why is Prism.Ioc missing from Prism.Wpf?
- Will the above conflict cause problems?
- Maybe I am missing something?

Thanks for your attention.
Peter

Comment: `Prism.Forms` is the platform specific package for Xamarin.Forms just like `Prism.Wpf` is for WPF.

Comment: Right, so we would still need Prism.Ioc in the Wpf package too :(

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, i.e. what is your issue?

Comment: I have to inject a service into one of my converters. But converters are instantiated by the Xaml framework => cannot inject a service.


Same issue as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49892472/how-to-resolve-a-dependency-in-ivalueconverter-in-xamarin-forms-using-prism-dryi

Seemingly it has been solved for Xamarin but not for Wpf! :(