# Specify cultureinfo in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, culture, typeconverter

I am developing a custom control for WinRT. I have a property with type CultureInfo. When I try to set this property in XAML, it shows following error.(But it shows possible values in intellisense.)

> Cannot assign text value 'af-ZA' into property 'Culture' of type
>   'CultureInfo'

What is the correct way to set this property from XAML?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the Culture property of the unnamed control takes a [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) object rather than a culture name. Create a CultureInfo object and assign it to the property, perhaps in the code behind.

It appears that [CultureInfoConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.cultureinfoconverter.aspx) class may not be available in WinRT. It is not in the WinRT [System.ComponentModel namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454035.aspx). Indeed, the TypeConverter class does not exist(see [WinRT Replacement for System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495937/winrt-replacement-for-system-componentmodel-typeconverter)) but [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) does so you could write your own.  See [How to inject a Converter in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900825/how-to-inject-a-converter-in-xaml) for information using a converter.